# Facebook OAuthToken in ACAccountCredential returns null on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios8, iphone-6

I have Facebook connect code using iOS Social API's that worked well on iPhone 5s/5 for iOS 7 & iOS 8. However when I just tested it on iPhone 6 the code fails with Facebook returning a null oauthToken even though accessGranted is true. Here's the code below where fbAccount returns the facebook account but without an oauthToken.

Any thoughts on what changed on iPhone 6?

```
NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
ACAccount *fbAccount = [accounts lastObject];
NSString *accessToken = [[fbAccount credential] oauthToken];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"token": accessToken};
```

Comment: Is your iPhone 6 running iOS 8.0 or iOS 8.1? We're receiving reports of the same problem for our app.

Comment: When you toggle off then toggle on Facebook access for your app, does the problem disappear?